# webpack: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve (with relative path)

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, relative-path

I have this structure of an app (`node_modules` dir excluded from this list):

```
├── actions.js
├── bundle.js
├── components
│   ├── App.js
│   ├── Footer.js
│   ├── Link.js
│   ├── Todo.js
│   └── TodoList.js
├── Containers
│   ├── AddTodo.js
│   ├── FilterLink.js
│   └── VisibleTodoList.js
├── index.html
├── index.js
├── main.js
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── reducers.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

My webpack config looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./main.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
              presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
          }
        ]
    }
};
```

npm config:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-redux",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "nothing"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  }
}
```

When I run `webpack` command, I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./components/App.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../containers/AddTodo' in '/home/oerp/js-programs/redux-test/components'
 @ ./components/App.js 11:15-47
 @ ./index.js
 @ ./main.js

ERROR in ./components/Footer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../containers/FilterLink' in '/home/oerp/js-programs/redux-test/components'
 @ ./components/Footer.js 11:18-53
 @ ./components/App.js
 @ ./index.js
 @ ./main.js

ERROR in ./components/App.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../containers/VisibleTodoList' in '/home/oerp/js-programs/redux-test/components'
 @ ./components/App.js 15:23-63
 @ ./index.js
 @ ./main.js
```

My `components/App.js` content is this:

```
import Footer from './Footer'
import AddTodo from '../containers/AddTodo'
import VisibleTodoList from '../containers/VisibleTodoList'

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <AddTodo />
    <VisibleTodoList />
    <Footer />
  </div>
)

export default App
```

And for example `containers/AddTodo.js`:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addTodo } from '../actions'

let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
  let input

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault()
          if (!input.value.trim()) {
            return
          }
          dispatch(addTodo(input.value))
          input.value = ''
        }}
      >
        <input
          ref={node => {
            input = node
          }}
        />
        <button type="submit">
          Add Todo
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
AddTodo = connect()(AddTodo)

export default AddTodo
```

It seems it does not understand relative path with double dots, like `../something`?

Do I need to configure `webpack` somehow for it to understand such paths?

Comment: Had the same issue. I solved it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64895428/10944219

Comment: `webpack --display-error-details` should help

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Your file structure says that folder name is `Container` with a capital C. But you are trying to import it by `container` with a lowercase c. You will need to change the import or the folder name because the paths are case sensitive.

Comment: This helped me too. windows had no problem with the file name beginning with capital but ubuntu had the problem.

Comment: I had a problem because I had an old webpack.config.js. We had switched to using a template webpack.config.babel.js and the old file was overriding the babel template when running webpack.

Comment: if you're somebody like me, developing on windows and CI/CD on Linux this happens. This solution helped me.

Answer (score 73):

I met this problem with `typescript` but forgot to add `ts` and  `tsx` suffix to `resolve` entry.

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
  },
};
```

This does the job for me

Comment: From [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveextensions) it is better to include defaults like so: `extensions: ['.ts', '...']`

Comment: Which file exactly? Lots of files have the same format. :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Okay, I found it. It is here: https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver/blob/HEAD/DOCS.md#extensions

Answer (score 11):

while importing libraries use the exact path to a file, including the directory relative to the current file, for example:

```
import Footer from './Footer/index.jsx'
import AddTodo from '../containers/AddTodo/index.jsx'
import VisibleTodoList from '../containers/VisibleTodoList/index.jsx'
```

Hope this may help

Comment: This isn't required, an import of `import Footer from './Footer'` is 100% valid

Comment: To be honest i do not recommend to put index file on each component directory. Better in my opinion is to use package.json file and indicate entry file in package.json, another option is to use Webapck directory plugin which i also do not recommend, because entire application will depend on webpack

Comment: Think it’s up to personal preference. At my company we have all Storybook stories, tests, CSS and supporting files in a directory for each component and it works great for us.

Answer (score 9):

You have to instruct the webpack to resolve the source code by using below code in webpack.config.js

```
module.exports={
   ...
   resolve:{
      extensions:['.js','.jsx'];
   }
}
```

Update : There is a new build tool *["Vite"](https://vitejs.dev/)* that aims to provide a faster and leaner development experience for modern web projects. Its is a plug and play tool, requires very less configuration.

Comment: would you use vite for node projects without a front-end?

Answer (score 6):

Just ran into this... I have a common library shared among multiple transpiled products. I was using symlinks with brunch to handle sharing things between the projects. When moving to webpack, this stopped working.

What did get things working was using webpack configuration to turn off symlink resolving.

i.e. adding this in `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    symlinks: false
  }
};
```

as documented here:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvesymlinks

Answer (score 5):

If you use multiple `node_modules` (yarn workspace etc), tell webpack where they are:

```
  externals: [nodeExternals({
    modulesDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules'),
  }),  nodeExternals()],
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem just after converting my project to TypeScript. The issue for me was that my project did not have a tsconfig.json file.
My solution was to create a new TypeScript project, and copy the tsconfig.json file from the newly created project into my project.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. I solved it by upgrading from the old  webpack@4.x and webpack-cli@4.x to webpack@5.x and webpack-cli@5.x.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue with module not found. Turns out I had a component 
`import Picture from './Picture/Picture';` at the very bottom of all the imports. When I moved it below `import React, { Component } from 'react';`, it worked.

Comment: Sounds like a circular import issue.

Answer (score -1):

Just add it to your config. Source: https://www.jumoel.com/2017/zero-to-webpack.html

```
externals: [ nodeExternals() ]
```

Comment: This is should be used only for backend

Comment: `Cannot find name 'nodeExternals'`

Answer (score -1):

Look the path for example this import is not correct 
**import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar.vue'**
should look like this 
** import Navbar from './components/Navbar.vue'**

Comment: I have a question..
How to get the vue base path? wish @ is vue base url,
then I can use @/components/Navbar.vue

Comment: @RobbyAlvianJayaMulia look into `tsconfig.json` "aliases" - you will also need to add these "aliases" to Webpack's resolvers

Answer (score -2):

I had a different problem. some of my includes were set to 'app/src/xxx/yyy' instead of '../xxx/yyy'

Answer (score -3):

changing `templateUrl: ''` to `template: ''` fixed it