# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app' in '/home/user/Desktop/my_app/src'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm starting to create my application, so I implemented the project configuration using webpack.
The project structure is:

```
node_modules
public
|----bundle.js
|----index.html
src
|----app.jsx
|----index.jsx
|----components
     |-----appBar.jsx
```

webpack.config.jsx:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.jsx'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        compress: true,
        port: 9000
    }
}
```

app.jsx:

```
import ButtonAppBar  from './components/appBar';
import React from 'react';


class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <ButtonAppBar />
            </div>
        )
    }
};

export default App;
```

index.html:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './app'


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

package.json:

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.5.1",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.17.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  }
```

I run this instruction:

```
webpack --display-error-details
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app' in '/home/user/Desktop/my_app/src'
resolve './app' in '/home/user/Desktop/my_app/src'
  using description file: /home/user/Desktop/my_app/package.json (relative path: ./src)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: /home/user/Desktop/my_app/package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/user/Desktop/my_app/src/app doesn't exist
      .wasm
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/user/Desktop/my_app/src/app.wasm doesn't exist
      .mjs
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/user/Desktop/my_app/src/app.mjs doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/user/Desktop/my_app/src/app.js doesn't exist
      .json
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/user/Desktop/my_app/src/app.json doesn't exist
      as directory
        /home/user/Desktop/my_app/src/app doesn't exist
[/home/user/Desktop/my_app/src/app]
[/home/user/Desktop/my_app/src/app.wasm]
[/home/user/Desktop/my_app/src/app.mjs]
[/home/user/Desktop/my_app/src/app.js]
[/home/user/Desktop/my_app/src/app.json]
 @ ./src/index.jsx 11:11-27
```

I found similar questions such as [webpack: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve (with relative path)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45968302/webpack-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-with-relative-path)  and  [Webpack 4 : ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772863/webpack-4-error-in-entry-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-src?rq=1)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In order to resolve your problem add the extensions to your `webpack.config.js`.

```
    module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  }
};
```

For more information take a look at [resolve.extensions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions)

Answer (score 7):

In `index.js` add the file extension to `app`.

```
import App from './app.jsx'
```

This is needed because you didn't add `resovle.extensions` option to the webpack config, so it searches for a folder named 'app' with `index.js` inside it.

[Webpack Resolve Docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and i was able to resolve it using the steps below;

1. To get more details about the error type `webpack --display-error-details`

this output something like: "field browser  doesn't contain a valid alias configuration"

2. i edit my `package.json`

`main: "./js/script.js"` this is the path to my js file

3.i edit my `settings.js`

`exports.themeLocation = './wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme'`

4. i edit my `webpack.config.js` - i added this line to module.exports

```
resolve: {
extensions:['.js', '.jsx']
},
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was I had two `resolve` block in my `webpack.config.js` which was causing issues!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the imports from the same folder starts with `./`

Example:

```
import component from './component';
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case. I got similar error when I forgot to put TypeScript configuration into container `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a case sensitivity problem in my index.js moving to a Linux container. In Windows it worked to have App.js but I had to rename it to app.js in order to build in Linux.